# Why are the two elements still sticking together despite having different layout_gravity?

Tags: android

The textbox with id totalTimeView and the ImageButton with id settings have layout_gravity left|top and right|top respectively, however they are still stuck together in the app. Why is this happening? Below is my xml file for the activity and I have attached a screenshot, thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    tools:context=".StoppedActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTimeView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/started_black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countDownView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalTimeView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:textColor="@color/started_black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="65sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totalTimeView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleSwitch"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countDownView"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why both are here, android:layout_gravity="right|top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totalTimeView", check the answer below

Comment: Did you try `layout_alignParentRight="true"` ?

Comment: You guys are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing, no need to use both in imageButton   android:id="@+id/settings" :

```
android:layout_gravity="right|top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totalTimeView"
```

Best thing is to use for imageButton, android:id="@+id/settings" :

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

and adjust other if need, but don't use redundant lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                tools:context=".StoppedActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTimeView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/started_black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countDownView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalTimeView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:textColor="@color/started_black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="65sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleSwitch"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countDownView"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You were using `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totalTimeView"` (ImageButton), that's why they were attached to each other. Plus, you have to add these 2 lines

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

to your `ImageButton` layout in order to move it to the far right of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `android:layout_gravity` for `settings` `ImageButton` to align it right side and top in `RelativeLayout` use:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

In same way align `totalTimeView` View at Top and left side of Layout:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```